# Remove substring which may contain special characters in Korn shell scripting

Tags: replace, ksh

I have some text with a password which may contain special characters (like /, *, ., [], () and other that may be used in regular expressions). How to remove that password from the text using Korn shell or maybe sed or awk? I need an answer which would be compatible with Linux and IBM AIX.

For example, the password is "123*(/abc" (it is contained in a variable).
The text (it is also contained in a variable) may look like below:
"connect user/123*(/abc@connection_string"

As a result I want to obtain following text:
"connect user/@connection_string"

I tried to use `tr -d` but received wrong result:

```
l_pwd='1234/\@1234'
l_txt='connect target user/1234/\@1234@connection'
print $l_txt | tr -d $l_pwd

connect target user\connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr -d` removes all characters in `l_pwd` from `l_txt` that's why the result is so strange.

Try this:

```
l_pwd="1234/\@1234";
escaped_pwd=$(printf '%s\n' "$l_pwd" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g')
l_txt="connect target user/1234/\@1234@connection";
echo $l_txt | sed "s/$escaped_pwd//g";
```

It prints `connect target user/@connection` in bash at least.

Big caveat is this does not work on newlines, and maybe more, check out where [I got this solution from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

With ksh 93u+

Here's some parameter expansion madness:

```bash
$ echo "${l_txt//${l_pwd//[\/\\]/?}/}"
connect target user/@connection
```

That takes the password variable, substitutes forward and back slashes into `?`, then uses that as a pattern to remove from the connection string.

---

A more robust version:

```bash
x=${l_pwd//[^[:alnum:]]/\\\0}
typeset -p x                        # => x='1234\/\\\@1234'

conn=${l_txt%%${x}*}${l_txt#*${x}}
typeset -p conn                     # => connect target user/@connection
```

Comment: l_txt='connect target user/o123*/.[]@connection_string';

l_pwd='o123*/.[]';

echo "${l_txt//${l_pwd//[\/\\]/?}/}"


ksh: "${l_txt//${l_pwd//[\/\\]/?}/}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: This is not only for slashes. All possible regexp characters may present in l_pwd (like /, *, [, ] and so on). There are no limitations on them

Comment: Can use `${l_pwd//[^[:alnum:]]/?}` but that might lead to false positives. I was trying to simply escape special characters (`${l_pwd//[^[:alnum:]]/\\\0}`) but couldn't get that working

Comment: Nope, sorry. The same error "ksh: "${l_pwd//[^[:alnum:]]/?}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command."

Comment: What version of ksh? I'm testing with `93u+`

Comment: It is definitely not ksh93. Something older IBM AIX has.

Comment: Do you have `perl` available? `echo "$l_txt" | perl -spe 's/\Q$pw\E//' -- -pw="$l_pwd"`